# Python Pandas: When trying to calculate rolling_std, is it possible to ignore a portion of the data in the time series and ONLY use the earlier data?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Python Pandas: When trying to calculate rolling_std, is it possible to ignore a portion of the data in the time series and ONLY use the earlier data?

For Example: S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
The first result would only take the std of (1,2,3) instead of (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Why not just filter the rows you're not interested in and then call `rolling_std`?

Comment: how do you choose 1,3,5 ? any rule ?

Comment: Can you link that doc please? @JohnE

Comment: Sure.  Here's the best place to start probably:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments

Comment: figured it out: .shift(n) is solution